# Infinite scroll – show same ad units multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, infinite-scroll, adsense, google-dfp

I have an ad unit

```
googletag.defineSlot('/67583982/en_728x90', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1526897670210-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
```

I want to show it in multiple place as user scroll , I have to show it multiple times.

But it shows only first time. After some reseach I realize that we show one ad unit only once on same page?

How can I add in infinite scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find its official documentation get an asnwer

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
 var slot = googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [728, 90], slotName).
     setTargeting("test","infinitescroll").
     addService(googletag.pubads());
```

Here is its link:-
[Tags on Pages with infinite content](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new DIV and define a slot for each new ad and give that slot a new ID which you pass in the defineSlot call.